# Не работает Update-Database (PostgreSQL) в приложении C# WPF (ЗАКРЫТ)

Tags: c#, wpf, база-данных, postgresql, .net-6

При выполнении команды `Add-Migration [Name] -verbose` всё проходит замечательно. Миграция собирается, база создаётся. Сделал правки в моделях, хочу обновить базу командой `Update-Database -verbose` и выдаёт следующую ошибку:

```
Failed executing DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType = 'Text', CommandTimeout = '30']
CREATE TABLE "Roles" (
    "Id" uuid NOT NULL,
    "Name" text NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "PK_Roles" PRIMARY KEY ("Id")
);
Disposing transaction.
'AppDBContext' disposed.
Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42P07: отношение "Roles" уже существует
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.<ReadMessage>g__ReadMessageLong|215_0(NpgsqlConnector connector, Boolean async, DataRowLoadingMode dataRowLoadingMode, Boolean readingNotifications, Boolean isReadingPrependedMessage)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult(Boolean async, Boolean isConsuming, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQuery(IEnumerable`1 migrationCommands, IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
  Exception data:
    Severity: ОШИБКА
    SqlState: 42P07
    MessageText: отношение "Roles" уже существует
    File: heap.c
    Line: 1202
    Routine: heap_create_with_catalog
42P07: отношение "Roles" уже существует
```

Нашёл что-то [подобное](https://translated.turbopages.org/proxy_u/en-ru.ru.087b9339-636f1be2-532a90e3-74722d776562/https/stackoverflow.com/a/8835441) в англоязычном сегменте стэка, но так и не понял, как исправить это.

Классы объектов:

### User

```
public class User
{
    // Код пользователя
    [Required]
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    // Роль пользователя
    [Required]
    [ConcurrencyCheck]
    public Guid? RoleId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("RoleId")]
    public Role Role { get; set; }


    // Изображение пользователя
    [ConcurrencyCheck]
    public byte[]? UserPic { get; set; }

    // Имя пользователя
    [Required]
    [ConcurrencyCheck]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    // Отчество пользователя
    [ConcurrencyCheck]
    public string? MiddleName { get; set; }

    // Фамилия пользователя
    [ConcurrencyCheck]
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    // Телефонный номер пользователя
    [ConcurrencyCheck]
    [Required]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    // Электронная почта пользователя
    [ConcurrencyCheck]
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    // Адрес пользователя
    public string? Address { get; set; }

    // Пароль пользователя
    [ConcurrencyCheck]
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    //Активирован ли аккаунт
    [ConcurrencyCheck]
    [Required]
    public bool IsActivated { get; set; }
}
```

### Role

```
public class Role
{
    // Код роли
    [Required]
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    // Название роли
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

### AppDBContext

```
public class AppDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }

    public AppDBContext()
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();

        if (this.Users.Count() == 0 && this.Roles.Count() == 0)
        {
            Role adminRole = new Role() { Name = "Администратор" };
            this.Roles.Add(adminRole);
            User adminUser = new User() {
                FirstName = [data],
                MiddleName = [data],
                LastName = [data],
                Role = adminRole,
                Email = [data],
                PhoneNumber = [data],
                Password = [data],
                IsActivated = true
            };
            this.Users.Add(adminUser);
            this.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        string _currentDBHost = RegistryService.GetRegistryKeySettings("DBHost");
        string _currentDBPort = RegistryService.GetRegistryKeySettings("DBPort");
        string _currentDBName = RegistryService.GetRegistryKeySettings("DBName");
        string _currentDBUser = RegistryService.GetRegistryKeySettings("DBUser");
        string _currentDBPassword = RegistryService.GetRegistryKeySettings("DBPassword");
        optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql($"Host={_currentDBHost};Port={_currentDBPort};Database={_currentDBName};Username={_currentDBUser};Password={_currentDBPassword}");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(u => u.IsActivated).HasDefaultValue(false);
    }
}
```

### UPD:

Поменял на Serial, как советовали в похожем посте - не помогло
[image: Поменял на Serial, как советовали в похожем посте - не помогло]

Comment: [Документация](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.databasefacade.ensurecreated?view=efcore-6.0#:~:text=%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%2C%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E%20%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%20%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%8F%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B6%D0%B5%20%D1%81%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E%20%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9.)

Comment: _Сделал правки в моделях_ - какие правки? Нужны модели **до** и **после**.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov любые, изменить тип параметра или название, результат один - ошибка

Comment: @EvgeniyZ "Обратите внимание, что этот API **не** использует миграции для создания базы данных. Кроме того, созданную базу данных нельзя обновить позже с помощью миграций." - эх, печально, конечно. Спасибо!

Comment: Я надеюсь, вы поняли, что нужно строку `Database.EnsureCreated();` удалить из кода?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov не совсем, но сейчас попробую

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov точно, сработало!!! Пришлось только удалить все предыдущие миграции (что в принципе не страшно). Спасибо большое!

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov починил по Вашему совету и на время оставил проект. Запускаю, хочу внести правки, но снова дичь какая-то происходит. Полностью удалил БД, и чтобы она создалась по миграции пришлось вернуть EnsureCreated() (иначе не работает), хочу обновить - тоже самое, как и было в основной теме вопроса "42P07: отношение "Roles" уже существует", но теперь уже не важно, удален ли EnsureCreated() или нет, ни в каком варианте не работает... Как с этим работать?

Comment: [Migrations Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli). В документации всё описано. / Сначала нужно создать миграцию: `migrations add`, затем обновлять `database update`. Это делается в консоли. / Если впендюрить в код `EnsureCreated`, то далее следует использовать [Database.Migrate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.migrate?view=efcore-6.0).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov я так и сделал. Убрал EnsureCreated. Add-Migration InitialCreate -verbose. Update-Database -verbose. Оно выдаёт ошибку, которую я описал в предыдущем сообщении. Посмотрел на метаните, абсолютно всё тоже самое, что делаю я, но у них ошибок нет :(